# Сериализация наследуемого класса

Tags: java, сериализация

Есть иерархия классов указанная ниже, для сериализации хватит ли имплиментировать Serializable только классу A, для сериализации классов типа C?

```
class A {

}
class B extends A{

}
class C extends B{

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Простой ответ: да, интерфейсы в Java наследуются.

Об этом, в частности, явно написано в документации [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> All subtypes of a serializable class are themselves serializable.
>
> *Все наследники сериализуемого класса сериализуемы.*

При этом надо иметь ввиду, что `Serializable` — интерфейс, который используется только чтобы отмечать классы, поддерживающие сериализацию. Класс, который отмечен как `Serializable` может содержать поля, сериализация которых невозможна.

```
class A implements Serializable {
}

//Класс В унаследовал интерфейс
class B extends A {
     //но содержит поля, которые не сериализуются
     Scanner scanner;
}
```

**Дополнение по несериализуемым полям:** При обнаружении несериализуемых полей при сериализации будет выброшено [NotSerializableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html). Это можно обойти несколькими способами, описанными в документации к `Serializable`, например в примере выше:

- объявить `scanner` как `transient`;
- переопределить методы сериализации;

но в этом случае сохранение и восстановление состояния несериализуемого поля нужно будет реализовывать самостоятельно.

Comment: Каждый объект, находящийся в классе B должен тоже имплементировать сериализацию?

Comment: @RodGers дополнил вопрос, надеюсь стало понятнее. Если можете, прочитайте документацию к [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) — она достаточно подробна.

Comment: @RodGers вот еще нашел статью на хабре с примерами по Serializable: https://habrahabr.ru/post/319604/

Comment: Огромно спасибо